# Connect tp-link router to a 802.1X network

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point, ieee802.1x

In my room, I have an ethernet cable, provided by my University, with a 802.1X authentication.

I have a Tp Link router, model tl-wr841n.

I want to connect it with the ethernet cable and make a wireless access point.
If I only plug in the ethernet cable in the router, it doesn't work.
What I have to do?

Comment: Plug the cable into the blue port is normally all you have to do. The university admin may need to authorize your device.

Comment: @harrymc is there a way to insert somewhere in the router configuration panel, my username and password for the network and make it work on my own?

Comment: There surely is. Read the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 802.1x authentication with username and password is done at the mobile device and not at the router.  On the router, you need to configure WPA/WPA2 Enterprise.   You need to add a Radius Server IP address and a port and Radius secret so that the username and password provided and the mobile device knows where to be routed. All this information can be provided to you by your University IT team.  Unfortunately, I don't think that they will provide you with that data - So you will be better off using the infrastructure provided to you by the University.